# How to read on a specific line and extract part of a string start with "abc" and end with "def"?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to print part of a string starting from "abc" an "def"
Example:

```
123456789
123abc_fff_def456789
123456789
...
```

Result:

```
abc_fff_def
```

Comment: and what have you try to do to accomplish that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `grep` supports the `-o` and `-P` non-standard options:

```
grep -Po 'abc.*?def' < your-file
```

Note that it assumes the `abc` and `def` are on the same line. It can report more than one occurrence per line.

`.*?` matches any sequence of 0 or more character, *as few as possible*, while `.*` would match *as many as possible*. That makes a difference on inputs like `0abc1def2def3` where with `.*?`, you'd get `abc1def` while with `.*`, you'd get `abc1def2def` (and on `0abc1def2abc3def4`, you'd get `abc1def` and `abc3def` vs `abc1def2abc3def`).

In any case, on an input like `0abc1abc2def3`, both would return `abc1abc2def` as it matches as *early* as possible.

To be able to match on multi-line data, you could use `perl` instead (the `P` in `grep -P` is actually for Perl-like regexps):

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print for /abc.*?def/gs' < your-file
```

Comment: Any benefit of using input redirection instead of specifiying the file directly like in my answer? Simply curious.

Comment: @Panki, see for instance [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756)

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` with a very simple regex allowing any potential characters between `abc` and `def`:

```
grep -o 'abc.*def' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
sed "s/[^a-z].[^a-z]//g" file


 grep -o "[a-z].*[a-z]" file
```

output

```
abc_fff_def
```

Comment: While that produces the expected output on the provided sample, that doesn't answer the question *How to read on a specific line and extract part of a string start with “abc” and end with “def”*

Answer (score 0):

Gnu sed we prefix with flag upon seeing /def/ and postfix with flag seeing  /abc/. Then we go on
a chopping spree, till we see /abc/
bubble upto the beginning of pattern space.

```
$ sed -ne '
    /\n/{/^abc.*def\n/P;D;}
    s/def/&\n/;s/abc/\n&/
    /\n.*\n/D
' file
```

With perl we assign appropriate values to  ORS => $\ based on whether pattern present. Only one pair printed

```
perl -lpe '
  $\    = /(abc.*?def)/ ? $/ : $,;
  $_=$1;
' file
```